# Simulate a javascript _dopostback using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, dopostback

Is there a way to convert a javascript:_doPostBack to an actual HTTP POST request using c# windows application? I **do not** want to perform this using an **ASP page**. I've been trying to figure out it, but have struck out so far. I know that typical doPostBacks handle the eventTarget and eventArgument.

Example:

```
  <td class="separator">
<a id="myStudentSearch_grdSearchResults__ctl3_lnkStudentName" class="link2" CommandType="Command" href="javascript:__doPostBack('myStudentSearch$grdSearchResults$_ctl3$lnkStudentName','')">Test                   Account                   </a>

javascript:__doPostBack('myStudentSearch$grdSearchResults$_ctl3$lnkStudentName','')
```

C: httpPost("http://xsite.com", "eventTarget=myStudentSearch$grdSearchResults$_ctl3$lnkStudentName&eventArgument=""");

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to simulate `__doPostBack`. What you probably want is to make an HTTP request that looks like it came from some page.

For that, I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/).

Once you know what to send, use `HttpClient`, `WebClient`, `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: I'm actually already using Fiddler, and it is a HTTP Post, that passes the event target, with the "myStudentSearch$grdSearchResults$_ctl3$lnkStudentName", followed by the viewstate. When I tried to duplicate the request in the composer, the post is successful, but the changes do not carry over.  I'v been scratching my head all night, trying to figure out why it doesn't like it.

Comment: What do you mean by not carry over?